# How to remove extra line feeds within double quoted fields

Tags: vb.net

Newbie here. Code below removes ALL line feeds in my file but it also removes EOR line feeds. Can somebody please help me how to fix code below so it only removes extra line feeds within double quoted fields? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Public Sub Main()
    '
    Dim objReader As IO.StreamReader
    Dim contents As String

    objReader = New IO.StreamReader("testfile.csv")
    contents = objReader.ReadToEnd()
    objReader.Close()

    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("testfile.csv")
    MsgBox(contents)
    'contents = Replace(contents, vbCr, "")
    contents = Replace(contents, vbLf, "")
    MsgBox(contents)
    objWriter.Write(contents)
    objWriter.Close()
    '
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

---

I forgot to mention that the input file name changes daily, How do I code so it doesn't care for the file name as long as it as a CSV file? So testfile name has current date and changes daily. I've tried just the file path and it errored out as well. Used the *.csv and it didnt like that either.

objReader = New IO.StreamReader("\FolderA\FolderB\TestFile09212022.csv")

Comment: Step 1 is going to be to process it into fields.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Don't know if it is an option, there are a heap of 3rd party libraries around, nugets among other places that make dealing with csv files trivial.  Could be worth the time to investigate feasibility before re-inventing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure there are no double quotes text inside the double quotes you can do it like this:

```
Dim sNewString As String = ""
Dim s As String
Dim bFirstQuoted As Boolean = False
Dim i As Integer

Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("testfile.csv")
MsgBox(contents)

For i = 1 To contents.Length
    s = Mid(contents, i, 1)
    If s = """" Then bFirstQuoted = Not bFirstQuoted
    If Not bFirstQuoted OrElse (s <> vbLf AndAlso bFirstQuoted) Then
        sNewString += s
    else
        sNewString += " "
    End If
Next

MsgBox(sNewString )
objWriter.Write(sNewString )
objWriter.Close()
Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

Comment: Miguel, this worked perfectly. I forgot to mention that the input file name changes daily, How do I code so it doesn't care for the file name as long as it as a CSV file?

Comment: The code worked but it appears that when the line feed was removed between multiple entries, it needs a space between the entries. How do I fix the code to insert a space between multiple entries?

Comment: For the extra space just check again the code, I added new lines: sNewString += " "

Comment: For that question about "any CSV file", well, will it have just one CVS file inside the directory? Just check the Vb command "Dir". If the file name is based on the date it will be easier, something like: Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("\FolderA\FolderB\TestFile" & Now.Date.ToString("MMddyyyy") & ".csv")

Comment: thank you for your help. This worked perfectly with the extra space as well

Comment: one more thing. Some data rows have columns that have blank values. Ex "12/01/2021",,"02/10/2022", - How do I code for those columns with blank values as you can see there are 2 consecutive commas but no pair of double quotes (" ") between the commas. How do I insert a pair of double quotes?

Comment: I have the following code but I am only able to insert just one set of double quotes and I need a pair because these double quotes are the column/field delimiters. How do I insert the second set? -             ss = Mid(contents, i, 2)
            If ss = ",," Then
                sNewString += """"
                sNewString += """"
            End If

Comment: I also tried the code below but it still just inserts one set of double quotes -             If ss = ",," Then
                'sNewString += """" 
                sNewString += """" + """"
            End If

Comment: It's easier than that, don't change anything, where you have the MsgBox(contents) just add a new line with: content = content.Replace(",,", "," & """""" & ",")